# Using a frame buffer yields strange results?

Tags: c#, opengl, framebuffer, opentk

I am very new to OpenGL (OpenTK), and I tried to get my first frame buffer working so I could apply post processing effects. However, when I try to draw the frame buffer it draws in the wrong place.

My rendering code is here:

```cs
                        protected override void OnRenderFrame(FrameEventArgs args)
        {
            GL.BindFramebuffer(FramebufferTarget.Framebuffer, this._frameBufferObject);

            //GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0);

            GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);

            GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest);

            GL.UseProgram(this._shaderProgramHandle);

            GL.BindVertexArray(this._vertexArrayHandle);
            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer, this._elementBufferObject);

            GL.DrawElements(PrimitiveType.Triangles, 6, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, 0);

            // Draw frame buffer

            GL.BindFramebuffer(FramebufferTarget.Framebuffer, 0);

            GL.ActiveTexture(TextureUnit.Texture0);
            GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, this._frameBufferTextureColorHandle);
            GL.ActiveTexture(TextureUnit.Texture0);

            GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit);

            GL.UseProgram(this._frameBufferProgramHandle);

            int screenTextureLocation = GL.GetUniformLocation(this._frameBufferProgramHandle, "screenTexture");
            GL.Uniform1(screenTextureLocation, 0);

            GL.BindVertexArray(this._rectangleVertexArrayObject);

            GL.Disable(EnableCap.DepthTest);

            GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.Triangles, 0, 6);

            this.Context.SwapBuffers();

            base.OnRenderFrame(args);
        }
```

And the code that creates the array object is here:

```cs
            this._rectangleVertexArrayObject = GL.GenVertexArray();
            this._rectangleVertexBufferObject = GL.GenBuffer();
            GL.BindVertexArray(this._rectangleVertexArrayObject);

            GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, this._rectangleVertexBufferObject);
            GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, rectangleVertices.Length * sizeof(float), rectangleVertices, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);

            GL.VertexAttribPointer(0, 2, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 4 * sizeof(float), 0);
            GL.VertexAttribPointer(1, 2, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 4 * sizeof(float), 2 * sizeof(float));

            GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(0);
            GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(1);

            GL.BindVertexArray(0);
```

My shader code if it makes a difference:

```cs
string vertexShaderCode = 
            @"
                #version 330 core

                layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPosition;
                layout (location = 1) in vec4 aColor;
                layout (location = 2) in vec2 aTexCoord;
                layout (location = 3) in float aTexId;

                out vec4 vColor;
                out vec2 texCoord;
                out float texId;

                void main(void)
                {
                    vColor = aColor;
                    texCoord = aTexCoord;
                    texId = aTexId;

                    gl_Position = vec4(aPosition, 1.0);
                }
            ";

                        string fragmentShaderCode = 
            @"
                #version 330 core

                in vec4 vColor;
                in vec2 texCoord;
                in float texId;

                uniform sampler2D[2] textures;

                out vec4 pixelColor;

                void main()
                {
                    if (texId == 0) {
                        pixelColor = texture(textures[int(0)], texCoord) * vColor;
                    }
                    else if (texId == 1) {
                        pixelColor = texture(textures[int(1)], texCoord) * vColor;
                    }
                }
            ";

            string frameBufferVertexShadeCode = 
            @"
                #version 330 core

                layout (location = 0) in vec2 aPosition;
                layout (location = 1) in vec2 aTexCoord;

                out vec2 texCoord;

                void main()
                {
                    gl_Position = vec4(aPosition.x, aPosition.y, 0.0, 1.0);
                    texCoord = aTexCoord;
                }
            ";

            string frameBufferFragmentShaderCode = 
            @"
                #version 330 core

                in vec2 texCoord;

                out vec4 pixelColor;

                uniform sampler2D screenTexture;

                void main()
                {
                    pixelColor = texture(screenTexture, texCoord);
                }
            ";
```

And here is the list of the rectangle vertices:

```cs
            float[] rectangleVertices =
            {
                // Coords    // texCoords
                +1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f, +0.0f,
                -1.0f, -1.0f, +0.0f, +0.0f,
                -1.0f, +1.0f, +0.0f, +1.0f,

                +1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f, +1.0f,
                +1.0f, -1.0f, +1.0f, +0.0f,
                -1.0f, +1.0f, +0.0f, +1.0f,
            };
```

The result created is also here

[image]

Comment: `textures[int(texId)]` doesn't work. It's an undefined behavior. See [OpenGL sampler2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72648980/opengl-sampler2d-array/72649578#72649578).

Comment: You still haven't refactored `textures[int(texId)]`. Converting it to an `if` statement doesn't change that. You can't trick the system like that. The indexing and the texture lookup still depends on `in float texId;`. In your case you can't use an array.

Comment: No, not in general. I think I pointed that out. However, if you only have 2 textures, you can do the following: `vec4 c0 = texture(textures[0], texCoord);`, `vec4 c1 = texture(textures[1], texCoord);`, `pixelColor = mix(c0, c1, texId) * vColor;`

Comment: If the framebuffers are of different sizes, you need to set the viewport with [`glViewport`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glViewport.xhtml) (`GL.Viewport`)

Comment: Is the correct way to put textures in the slots with sampler2DArray GL.Uniform1?